# what is the difference between "this" and "xxx.this" in android

Tags: android, this

example:
Why can I write like that `MainActivity.this.getContentResolve();`
but can not write like that `this.getContentResolve();` in `MainActivity.java`

Comment: Maybe you are trying to access to this inside another object declaration like  in a listener. In that case this doesn't refer to MainActivity, and thats why you have to use MainActivity.this to access to it.

Comment: If you are trying to get activity instance within thread or inside any callback method than you need to specify the activityname.this

Comment: The MainActivity.this.getContentResolve() syntax is useful when you have a non-static nested class that needs to refer to its outer class's instance.

Comment: What `this` refers to changes depending on where you are calling it from. When you call `MainActivity.this` you're making sure to refer to `this` instance of the activity.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access instance of enclosing class from inner class you need to make declaration like this - ClassName.this.anyClassMethod();

For more info read this article [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference if you are calling `getContentResolver()` from any direct method of the activity. You can write both `MainActivity.this.getContentResolver();` and `this.getContentResolver();` as well as simply `getContentResolver()` with the same effect. In this case, the `this` keyword refers to the current instance of the MainActivity.

However, if you are within an inner class or inside an implementation of an interface/abstract method inside the MainActivity, then `this` will refer to an instance of the inner class or the interface you are implementing. In that case, you have to call `MainActivity.this` to get access to the instance of the `MainActivity`.

Comment: that is not the case when you try like this within a callback, listener method or while running on thread.

Comment: @Dexto You commented before I completed typing my answer.

Comment: This answer is an important point for this question. Check where `this`s are called in `MainActivity` first.

Comment: @IshitaSinha post edit you have provided correct answer before that the answer does not satisfied the question.

Comment: @Dexto Yes, I had accidentally clicked on the button, so I had to edit. :(

Answer (score 0):

This syntax becomes relevant when using inner classes.

```java
public class A {
    String str = "A";

    public class B {
        String str = "B";

        public String getStr() {
            return A.this.str; //returns A
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's long described but i think your question is related to anonymous class.

When you are inside class and want to refer to the current object of the class you can use `this` for example:

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    int foo;

    public Test(int _foo){

    this.foo = _foo;
    }
}
```

but when you want to refer to the current class object from anonymous class inside it you should use `class.this` for example:

```
MyActivity.this
```

Full example for Inner Class:

```
    public class Test {

        int foo = 1;

        public class InnerTest {
            public String getFoo() {
                return Test.this.foo;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why can I write like that  `MainActivity.this.getContentResolve()` but
>   can not write like that `this.getContentResolve()`?

Because your trying to access the context of outer class (MainActivity) in the inner class. we use `TheActivityClassName.this` in the inner class to access the outer `TheActivityClassName` class’s context.

When we are accessing the activity context in inner class we need a reference to the activity class name so we pass it like `MainActivity.this`

and when we need it in the class then we can reference it simply like `this.something`

You should have a look [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-Context) to get good grasp on what context is actually

Hope it helps